# How can I use Serilog to catch Unhandled Exceptions in the App.cs of a .NET MAUI application?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, maui, serilog

I'm using Azure Table Storage to as a storage mechanism. I'm able to write exceptions within a ViewModel to the Azure Table from within the ViewModel, but when I try to add a handler to unhandled exceptions on `App.cs` the exception is logged on the Debug output window, but it isn't stored on the Azure Table.

This is my `Program.cs`:

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                fonts.AddFont("SF-Pro-Text-Bold.otf", "SFProTextBold");
                fonts.AddFont("SF-Pro-Text-Regular.otf", "SFProTextRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf", "MaterialDesignIcons");
            });

        builder.UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .RegisterDataServices()
            .RegisterViewModels()
            .RegisterViews();

        builder.Logging.AddSerilog();

        var storageConnectionString = "MY_CONNECTION_STRING";
        var tableName = "logs";

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.AzureTableStorage(connectionString: storageConnectionString, storageTableName: tableName)
            .WriteTo.Debug()
            .CreateLogger();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

This is my App.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        private readonly ILogger<App>_logger;

        public App(ILogger<App> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            InitializeComponent();
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleUnhandledException;
            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }

        private void HandleUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            var exception = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
            _logger.LogCritical(exception, exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is one of my ViewModels where I'm implementing logging:

```
public class OnboardingViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ILogger<OnboardingViewModel> _logger;

    public OnboardingViewModel(ILogger<OnboardingViewModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    private void OnSkipOnboardingCommand()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Oops! Something went wrong.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try this the exception is shown on the output window and saved to the Azure Table:

[image]

However if I change the `OnSkipOnboardCommand` to this:

```
private void OnSkipOnboardingCommand()
{
    throw new Exception("Oops! Unhandled Exception.");
}
```

I receive the exception on the `HandleUnhandledException` methond on `App.cs`. The exception is logged only to the Output Window:

```
[0:] [07:38:43 FTL] Oops! Unhandled Exception.
System.Exception: Oops! Unhandled Exception.
   at MyApp.Mobile.ViewModels.OnboardingViewModel.OnSkipOnboardingCommand() in C:\Users\Developer\Development\MyApp\src\MyApp.Mobile\ViewModels\OnboardingViewModel.cs:line 74
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Command.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<.ctor>b__0(Object o) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Command.cs:line 80
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Command.Execute(Object parameter) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Command.cs:line 123
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TapGestureRecognizer.SendTapped(View sender, Func`2 getPosition) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\TapGestureRecognizer.cs:line 59
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.TapGestureHandler.OnTap(Int32 count, MotionEvent e) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Platform\Android\TapGestureHandler.cs:line 69
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.InnerGestureListener.Android.Views.GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener.OnSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Platform\Android\InnerGestureListener.cs:line 157
   at Android.Views.GestureDetector.IOnGestureListenerInvoker.n_OnSingleTapUp_Landroid_view_MotionEvent_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_e) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-33/mcw/Android.Views.GestureDetector.cs:line 711
   at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_Z(_JniMarshal_PPL_Z callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 137
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualBooleanMethod(JniObjectReference instance, JniObjectReference type, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 11969
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualBooleanMethod(String encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:line 164
   at Android.Views.GestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-33/mcw/Android.Views.GestureDetector.cs:line 1639
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.TapAndPanGestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Platform\Android\TapAndPanGestureDetector.cs:line 36
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.GesturePlatformManager.OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Platform\GestureManager\GesturePlatformManager.Android.cs:line 83
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.GesturePlatformManager.OnPlatformViewTouched(Object sender, TouchEventArgs e) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Platform\GestureManager\GesturePlatformManager.Android.cs:line 204
   at Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListenerImplementor.OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-33/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:line 4196
   at Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListenerInvoker.n_OnTouch_Landroid_view_View_Landroid_view_MotionEvent_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_v, IntPtr native_e) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-33/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:line 4137
   at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLL_Z(_JniMarshal_PPLL_Z callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0, IntPtr p1) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 236
```

However the exception is not persisted on Azure Storage. This only happens with the exceptions on the `HandleUnhandledException` method on the `App.cs`.

The fact the the exception is written to the Output Window but not to the Azure Table really confuses me.

Any idea on why this is happening or how I could get Unhandled Exceptions and store them on Azure Tables using Serilog? Should I change something on my code?

What I found

Comment: writing a message to the output log and opening a connection to a remote server and transmitting a log file are very different things.  Most crash reporting tools write logs to a local file and only upload them to a server when the app restarts.  While the OS is forcibly closing the app due to a crash there is not time to reliably write to a remote server.

Comment: I highly recommend to use Sentry for unhandled exceptions in Maui apps.  So simple and effective!  https://sentry.io/for/dotnet-maui/

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith that was it, OS closing the app too fast. A hacky WriteToLog(e).Wait() made it work for now. :)

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith I wasn't familiar with Sentry but holly heck, that was exactly what I was looking for, now I would have to implement Grafana, or maybe even change to ElasticSearch to have some information on my logs, but from a quick overview of Sentry it seems like I might even ditch Serilog. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a few options here:

- The exception is being caught before it can bubble up to the app domain's `UnhandledException` event handler. I'm not familiar with how MAIU handles its logging of errors to the console, but perhaps this could be the issue.
- In your `CreateMauiApp` method, where you're setting up your app and registering the view model, view, etc, it's possible that the `OnSkipOnboardingCommand` is being invoked before the `HandleUnhandledException` handler has been wired up to the app domain's `UnhandledException` event. You can test this by wiring up the `UnhandledException` event handler at the start of the `CreateMauiApp` method.
- As already pointed out by a commenter on your post, it's possible that your process doesn't have enough time to write the log to the Azure table before it's been killed by the OS. You could test to see if this is the issue, by changing the `ExitApplication` property to `false` on the `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` object, which will allow it to remain running.

I'd also recommend reading Microsoft's documentation for the `UnhandledException` event, from memory you won't be able to catch certain classes of critical exceptions with it.

Comment: You're right on the third point. Has had already been pointed out on another comment the problem seems to be that the OS kills the app before Serilog has time to log the exception on Azure Tables. UnhandledExceptionEventArgs doesn't contain a definition for ExitApplication  (I'm on .NET 8 Preview, maybe because of this), but a hacky WriteToLog(e).Wait(); inside the HandleUnhandledException delegate handler made it work. Will try to look into another alternatives, Sentry.io as mentioned in another comment worked amazing.

Comment: @adamasan, glad it's working for you! Yeah, there's some really nice tools for logging nowadays, definitely the sort of thing to go with rather than rolling your own, if it doesn't cost an arm and a leg.

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful discussions going on here
[image]

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/653
old but gold
https://peterno.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/unhandled-exception-handling-in-ios-and-android-with-xamarin/